# explain by what criteria threejs assigns id to Obejct3d

Tags: three.js

there is an array of objects in the json file, the objects have current information about *.obj files and their paths. when referring to json as [...jsondata] array and calling each object in the scene through for(i=0; i<jsondata.lenght; i++) all are right, all objects are called up and the stage is lined up. But! The object.id assignment order is not the same as in the jsondata array, and for some reason always starts with id: 96. And most importantly id is not editable, and for me it is very important that the order in the scene was the same as in json. Can someone explain by what criteria threejs assigns this id?

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on the [`Object.id` property](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object#api/en/core/Object3D.id) to maintain any desired order. These are automatically generated, and they can add up quickly if any of your `*.obj` files have children, grandchildren, lights, cameras, etc.

For example, if you want 2 `car`s with `id = 1 & 2`, each part of the car *could* have a new id, depending on how it was built:

```
window: 2,
wheels: 3,
headlamps: 4,
light: 5
```

By the time you start car # 2, you're already on `id = 6`.

If you want to store a specific attribute in certain objects, you could use the [`.userData` property](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object#api/en/core/Object3D.userData) to store it.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
   object[i].userData.order = i;
}
```

Or just create your own array to access them in order later:

```js
const orderedItems = [];
for(let i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
   orderedItems.push(someObject);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I once again carefully studied my *.obj files and as I think I found the criterion by which three orders the order of uploading files to the scene - this is the number of vertices in the obj file, as an example if 1.obj has 2000 vertices and 2.obj has 1000 vertices, then in the ID first note will go 2.obj file.